# generate django 2.0 model from a dict

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.0

Consider the following Django model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I would like to define this class from a “static” dict *(to be specific in my case it is generated from a file which will not change - so no need to `makemigrations` and `migrate` apart from first time)*.

Here is some pseudo-code to better explain what I want to achieve:

```
persondict = {‘first_name‘: models.CharField(max_length=255), ‘last_name’: models.CharField(max_length=255)}

class Person(models.Model):
    #generate fields from persondict
```

Comment: There is Django docs about it: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

Comment: @SzymonP. Is where I got the example but seems very outdated, the part after "is functionally equivalent to" produces a KeyError: '__module__'. Could you provide a minimum working solution for this simple exemple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to start with. Note that you have to change the app_label inside the function, also this will work if you define it inside your models.py where you will use it, otherwise you will need to replace the '__module__' with the appropriate value.

```
def generate_person_model_from_a_dict(person_model_dict):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'your_app_label_here'

    person_model_dict.update({
        'Meta': Meta,
        '__module__': generate_person_model_from_a_dict.__module__,
    })

    Person = type("Person", (models.Model,), person_model_dict)
    return Person
```

`Meta.app_label` is needed here to let the Django know which app the newly constructed model should be attached to, e.g. if you are creating it for the app `blog` and set the model's `app_label` to `blog`, then the Django will know, that the app has this model on it (just like you would define it in your `blog/models.py`)

`__module__` is a special attribute of python objects (you can read details about it here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html ) To be brief, it lets Django to know which module your class belongs to, it uses it mostly to display various messages to it's user, see here: [https://github.com/django/django/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=**module**&type=](https://github.com/django/django/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__module__&type=)
(just set it to your models.py like in the above example is therefore what Django pretty much expects)

Comment: good answer, worked for me. Would be great to elaborate on the use of  Meta, app_label and __module__ to give a more detailed explanation. Got a vague general understanding with (warning: obsolete) https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels but it would be great if you were to explain it in some details here.Then I will happily accept your answer.

Comment: @shrimpdrake, added some details, hope they will help you